# ASP.NET TextBox updated by Javascript not seen

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

This is going to be easy for someone who knows what they are doing.

I have a launch calendar button, a continue button, and a date textbox.  The button launches a JavaScript calendar in a popup window.  That calendar returns a date into the ReservationDate textbox field using:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('ctl00_wpm_ShowProduct_ctl10_ReservationDate').value = '<%= CurrentDate %>';
```

I know, it's not elegant but works.  The problem is that even though on the browser I see the date in the field, when I hit the continue button and try to access it from my .NET script, the server side script sees it as empty.

How do I tell the server to use the text the browser has in that field that it is not seeing?

I know enough to know that it's a server side versus client side issue but how do I bridge that gap?

Comment: Do you have any other code hat may be overwriting that value earlier in the page lifecycle?

Comment: If you're able to see the text in the field before you submit the postback, then I think something is probably wrong in your code behind. You're probably not checking `IsPostBack` Can you post that code as well?

Comment: @Chad, than he wouldn't be able to compile  He sees it as empty, not as inexisting

Comment: Yeah i put that together when i reread and looked at the control name.

Comment: it would be a good idea to post your html, and server side script too. do you have runat="server" in the textbox declaration? when you try to access the textbox, is it found on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have set your textbox as ReadOnly and that seems to be an issue. 
Set it readonly like this in code behind:

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
```

Check [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2007/05/10/112390.aspx).

Comment: Brilliant gbs!  It threw me off that I could see the value onscreen and never considered readonly.  Thank you for solving a problem that's making me crazy this week... I'm sure there will be a new one next week. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you initialize the value in the Page_Load, the value will get lost.
I guess it must be something like that.

So you would write in your Page_Load:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
Initialize();
}
```

Comment: I would be willing to bet that this is the problem. Hard to tell without seeing the code though.